# facing animation issue while creating typing cursor effect in CSS steps()

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to create typing cursor effect in css using steps() after playing this for quite a while i couldn't find why this is behaving abnormally, I want the cursor to appear and disappear after specified time period. but it appears and fades half way. what could be causing this behavior?

```
please have a look at the fiddle.   
https://jsfiddle.net/jL1f4rzc/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I preffer not use steps to this, instead I use percents in the animation like this:

```
.blink {
 animation : blink 1s 0s infinite;
 animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes blink {
 0% {
  border-right:2px solid #000;
 }
 70% {
  border-right:2px solid #000;
 }
 75% {
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
 }
 100% {
   border-right: 2px solid transparent;
 }
}
```

[fiddle Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/jL1f4rzc/1/)

Comment: That's a very creative use of percentages to attain that effect without steps, but i would really like to know how could we implement steps to create the desired effect, because using steps is intuitive when it comes to these kind of effect, and it will help me understand how the property works at the core.

Answer (score 0):

I was checking how to do it with steps ;D

The answer is not so logical for me

```
.blink {
 animation : blink 0.8s steps(2,end) 0s infinite;
}
.cursor {
 border: 0px solid transparent;
 border-right:0px solid #000;
}

@keyframes blink {
 from {
  border-right-width: 0px;
  }
 to {
  border-right-width: 2px;
 }
}
```

And works fine, but if I change the animation to:

```
@keyframes blink {
 from {
  border-right-width: 2px;
  }
 to {
  border-right-width: 0px;
 }
}
```

Doesn't work O_o! 
I hope this version be useful for you.
[fiddle Updated 2](https://jsfiddle.net/jL1f4rzc/2/)

Comment: nice! well, previous solution requires less code, so ill go with that! thanks for this aswell!